# Why is the length of an array 1 greater than expected?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print out the column size and the row size of a two-dimensional array. My program compiles but it prints out:

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\Users\mulk\Downloads
> run Lab4
Print out the rowsize:  4.0
Print out the  columnsize:  4.0
>
```

Shouldn't the row size be 3.0? I am counting from zero.

```
/*
 * Purpose: Prints the row and column averages
 */
class Lab4
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

     int [][] scores = {{ 20, 18, 23, 20, 16 },
                        { 30, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
                        { 16, 19, 16, 53, 24 },
                        { 25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
     outputArray(scores);
  }

  public static void outputArray(int[][] array)
  { 
    double rowsize = 0.0;
    double columnsize= 0.0;
    for(double i=0.0;i <= array.length;i++)
    {
      rowsize = array.length;
    }
    System.out.println("Print out the rowsize:  " +rowsize);

    for (double j = 0; j <=array[0].length; j++)
    {
      columnsize = array.length;
    }
    System.out.println("Print out the  columnsize:  " +columnsize);
  }
}
```

Comment: Size starts from 1, indexing starts from 0. If you have one row, it might be indexed as row 0 (depending on the language), but we still say the "size" is 1.

Comment: As Eric already said, but... you could just `System.out.println("rows: " + scores.length);` and `System.out.println("cols: " + scores[0].length);`

Answer (score 0):

2D arrays are just an array of arrays. So to find out how many rows there are we would do arrayName.length and then to find out how many items are in each column we would have to go to the first row (array) and find out that length by arrayName[0].length.

so as you can see the code you are using finds out how many rows there are twice. It should look something like this:

```
    double rowsize = 0.0;
    double columnsize= 0.0;

    rowsize = array.length;
    System.out.println("Print out the rowsize:  " +rowsize);

    if(rowsize >= 1){
        columnsize = array[0].length;
    }
    System.out.println("Print out the  columnsize:  " +columnsize);
```

I hope this has solved your issue :)